# Сравнение двух массивов

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при сравнении двух массивов,когда находится первый одинаковый элемент, поиск заканчивался и этот элемент записывался в 3 массив. В примере получается массив с: ((A-B))+C, а нужно чтобы выводился такой результат:
массив с: (A-B)+C
массив a:()
в массиве а оставшиеся элементы!

```js
var a = "ABC()-()+";
var b = "(A-B)+C";
var c = [];

document.write("массив а:  ");
document.write(a);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив b:  ");
document.write(b);

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (b[i] == a[j]) {
      c.push(b[i]);
    }
  }
}
document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив c:  ");
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив a:  ");
document.write(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вам нужен [оператор break](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

для изменения массива `a` можно воспользоваться [методом replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var a = "ABC()-()+";
var b = "(A-B)+C";
var c = [];

document.write("массив а:  ");
document.write(a);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив b:  ");
document.write(b);

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (b[i] == a[j]) {
      c.push(b[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  a = a.replace(b[i],'');
}

document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив c:  ");
document.write(c.join(''));
document.write("<br>");
document.write("массив a:  ");
document.write(a);
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы в массиве а выводились оставшиеся элементы,  в данном случае: массив а : ()

Comment: нужно менять массив а тоже, в данном коде он не меняется

Comment: @Светлана, обновил ответ

Comment: все поняла, спасибо)

Comment: _"для изменения массива a"_ :( И где там _массив_ a?

Comment: @Qwertiy, считай строку массивом символов :)